# Changing dialog title conditionally jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello I am working on creating dialog using jquery and asp.net mvc3.

I want to change dialog title depending upon certain condition.

e.g

```
$("#mydiv").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    @
    if (model.Correct) //Condition to change title
    title: "Correct",
    else title: "Incorrect",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    position: [500, 200],
    hide: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 1000
    },
    show: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 1000
    }
});
```

Of course that code there would look foolish. but i have only put condition only to depict my requirement

Any Solutions?

Comment: what backend are u usin ror??

Comment: asp.net mvc3 and sql server 2008

Comment: what error is it giving now??

Comment: No u cant use model values inside dialog

Comment: What happens when you try this: `title: (@Model.Correct ? "Correct" : "Incorrect");`

Comment: I tried that but it gives error in html formatiing

Comment: thanks both for ur response. solved using below code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have done it using below code

```
var dialogTitle;

if ("@Model.Correct" == "True") {
    dialogTitle = "Correct";
} else {
    dialogTitle = "Incorrect";
}

$("#mydiv").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    title: dialogTitle,

    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    position: [500, 200],


    hide: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 1000
    },
    show: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 1000
    }
});
```